# Is it possible to partially deallocate memory?

Tags: c++, c, free

In C (or C++) I'm wondering if it's possible to partially deallocate a block of memory.

For example, suppose we create an array of integers `a` of size 100,

```
int * a = malloc(sizeof(int)*100);
```

and then later we want to resize `a` so that it holds 20 ints rather than 100.

Is there a way to free only the last 80*sizeof(int) bytes of `a`? For example if we call realloc, will it do this automatically?

- **I'm looking for a solution that doesn't require moving/copying the first 20 ints.**
- Alternatively, can you explain either why it would be bad if this were possible, or why the ability to do this wasn't included in either language?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can use [realloc](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdlib/realloc/), but you should definitely consider using STL containers instead of manually allocating memory.

Comment: Doesn't realloc copy the array and then free the original?

Comment: @Cam, no.  It is allowed to (and often will) shrink the existing region.

Comment: @watson1180: Right, but that alone means nothing. In principle realloc could be implemented to take O(n!^99) time and always allocate 500 times the necessary memory, but we certainly don't factor that in when making decisions involving realloc.

Comment: @watson, what real implementation of `realloc` doesn't return memory to the system?  Note that either shrink in place or move, copy, free old will return memory.

Answer (score 3):

We prefer RAII containers to raw pointers in C++.

```
#include <vector>

// ...

{
    std::vector<int> a(100)
    // ...
    std::vector<int>(a.begin(), a.begin() + 20).swap(a);
}
```

Comment: It should be noted that this doesn't really "partially deallocate memory."  This allocates a new block of the desired size, copies the contents from the original block, and then frees the original block.

Comment: resize() does not have to adjust the allocated memory. Even clear() does not have to.

Comment: Agree. resize doesn't have to free memory. On all implementation I know resize leaves the capacity of vector unchanged.

Answer (score 2):

I would prefer using a `std::vector`. Let's enable C++0x:

```
std::vector<int> vec(20);
vec.reserve(100);

// do something

vec.shrink_to_fit();
```

From n3092 (not the so final draft, I need to get a fresh copy on this PC):

`void shrink_to_fit();`

Remarks: `shrink_to_fit` is a non-binding request to reduce memory use. *[ Note: The request is non-binding to allow latitude for implementation-specific optimizations. —end note ]*